# How to install Bastion from .sh file?

Tags: games, scripts

I have downloaded Bastion from HIB V; though, when I execute the .sh file in Terminal, nothing happens. Can anybody help me installing it?
Thank you :)

Comment: I realise this probably doesn't help after a gigabyte download, but why didn't you just install it through the software center?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same as you would anything else:

- Right click it, Properties, Permissions, check the "Allow executing file as program" box. Then double click the file.
- Or `chmod +x file; ./file`

Comment: I've already did that and it didn't work this morning; now it works! This is strange. <br /> Thanks Oli :)

Answer (score -1):

You have to write:

```
sudo ./filename.sh
```

And it will run the installer as root.

This worked for me after installing the file `libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0.deb`.

Comment: Most of these installers (including the Bastion one) actually do not need to be run as root. They place files in special parts of your home folder instead of in system-wide places. There is an _option_ to install in a system place, in which case the installer will need escalated privileges (and it might ask for that on its own, depending on how shiny and new it is).

Comment: A `.deb` file installed as `root` because it installs a package for the whole system. Furthermore, you install a `.deb` file with `sudo dpkg -i filename.deb`, not `sudo ./filename.deb`. (There are sometimes scripts that have `.deb` in their name that are installed this way, though, e.g., `sudo ./filename.deb.run`.) In general, as [Dylan McCall](http://askubuntu.com/users/2992/dylan-mccall) says, you should only run a program with `sudo` if you know it needs to run as root, and this includes installers. Only install as `root` if you know you're doing a *systemwide* installation.